# Post rating system on Wordpress Heroku blog

Tags: wordpress, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to install on my blog a system that allow post rating and add in the sidebar the top ten of most rated post...
For this i am trying to use much cummon plugins, such as:

contestant-rating, post-ratings, buddypress-rate-forum-posts, rate-my-whatever

also this:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/

that looks to be better of all...

But nothing they won't work correctly...it seems to have problem with PostgresSQL DB...

Do you know this issue? if yes, have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is done for the MySQL initially. There's an extension for [using PostgreSQL with it](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postgresql-for-wordpress/), and it even works (we're using it for small blog).

Unfortunately, many plugins are designed to query database directly, not via the Wordpress layer. If this is the case, then you have either to modify such plugin, or look for something else.

There're some movements towards support of more databases, but it is [work in progress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases).